# Caffe Framework Runtest Core dumped error

Tags: cuda, deep-learning, caffe

I have been installing Caffe Framework with the following GPU:
Geforce 9500 GT
CUDA 6.5 (not work with 7.0)

when I run: `make runtest` the following errors appeared and I don't know what are the reasons:

```
 make runtest
.build_debug/tools/caffe
caffe: command line brew
usage: caffe <command> <args>

commands:
  train           train or finetune a model
  test            score a model
  device_query    show GPU diagnostic information
  time            benchmark model execution time

  Flags from tools/caffe.cpp:
    -gpu (Run in GPU mode on given device ID.) type: int32 default: -1
    -iterations (The number of iterations to run.) type: int32 default: 50
    -model (The model definition protocol buffer text file..) type: string
      default: ""
    -snapshot (Optional; the snapshot solver state to resume training.)
      type: string default: ""
    -solver (The solver definition protocol buffer text file.) type: string
      default: ""
    -weights (Optional; the pretrained weights to initialize finetuning. Cannot
      be set simultaneously with snapshot.) type: string default: ""
.build_debug/test/test_all.testbin 0 --gtest_shuffle 
Cuda number of devices: 1
Setting to use device 0
Current device id: 0
Note: Randomizing tests' orders with a seed of 60641 .
[==========] Running 1356 tests from 214 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 10 tests from PowerLayerTest/3, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[ RUN      ] PowerLayerTest/3.TestPower
F0616 20:08:47.978885 31913 math_functions.cu:81] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (11 vs. 0)  invalid argument
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x2b2716c57daa  (unknown)
    @     0x2b2716c57ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x2b2716c576e6  (unknown)
    @     0x2b2716c5a687  (unknown)
    @     0x2b27187a66fd  caffe::caffe_gpu_memcpy()
    @     0x2b27186fa15d  caffe::SyncedMemory::to_gpu()
    @     0x2b27186f9b44  caffe::SyncedMemory::gpu_data()
    @     0x2b27186a4701  caffe::Blob<>::gpu_data()
    @     0x2b27187b3a70  caffe::PowerLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
    @           0x4adaca  caffe::Layer<>::Forward()
    @           0x5a033e  caffe::PowerLayerTest<>::TestForward()
    @           0x59f381  caffe::PowerLayerTest_TestPower_Test<>::TestBody()
    @           0x7cf479  testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x7caa12  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x7b7e29  testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x7b85c2  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x7b8bb0  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x7bda3a  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x7d04ac  testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x7cb6c9  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x7bc7ce  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x480a13  main
    @     0x2b27196a1ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x480819  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
make: *** [runtest] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: The 9500 GT is Compute Capability 1.1. This compute capability doesn't support double precision, and the test is attempting to use double precision from the looks of things, hence the crash. I don't know if there's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Jez.I have searched for the workaround for a while. However, the only solution mostly is to use newer card

Comment: @duccuong: please add your conclusions as a short answer. This will get there question off the unanswered list and help others who might have the same problem in the future

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (as @Jez suggested) my GPU does not support double precision which used by Caffe math functions. That's the reason for crashes. I have searched for workaround on this issue but haven't found one. Maybe the only solution is to use more modern GPU

Comment: Certainly the "modern" way to use caffe on CUDA GPUs includes use of the cuDNN library, and the cuDNN library requires a cc3.0 or higher GPU.